# How to use Unity on an 18.04 Live-USB?

Tags: unity, live-usb, 18.04, lightdm

I wanted to test Unity out on a live-USB image of Ubuntu 18.04.

Obviously Unity is no longer the default, so after booting, I used `sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop` to install Unity and configured lightdm to be default display manager.

After logging out, however, the default display manager did not change. And rebooting meant losing all of the changes on the live-USB.

How can I use Unity on a live-USB image of Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: why change gdm for lightdm? you should still be able to change sessions from gdm

Comment: I am going  to guess you will have to make a custom iso. You should be able to do this with the debian live scripts rather easily, it will take a bit to read the documentation is all. Your other option would be to install and configure on the usb

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). What are you actually trying to achieve? Do you really want or need to replace the display manager or does the Unity user session suffice?

Comment: gdm3, unlike lightdm,  will not show any added session until after a reboot. If you want to try then put in a small install or do what Panther suggested. (- if *properly set up* unity works fine in 18.04, best it's ever been in many respects.

Comment: I actually thought you needed lightdm to run Unity in 18.04, since I couldn't find a way to switch desktop environments with gdm. Anyhow, I could care less about the dipsplay manager: my goal is simply to try out 18.04 with Unity so I can figure out if I can upgrade, or if a lot of stuff is broke (I read somewhere that the HUD wasn't working right?). I've tried the default GNOME environment... let's just say it's really, really not for me.